# Mat-Table : Scroll a row into view in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, mat-table, angular-cdk

Is it possible to scroll a specific data row into view when using the angular material mat-table `cdk-table`?

I'm trying to implement keyboard scrolling with no luck.

Comment: It's really difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What i want to do is to select the next or prev row in the mat-table by the keyboard. The selection is working as expected. Now i only need to have the selected/current row visible in view.  in the stackblitz example you can see it. It's a changed example of a mat-table demo. https://stackblitz.com/edit/mensand-rowselect?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Comment: You have something that kind of works, that's a starting point. Now, if you provide a stackblitz example of you currently have we might be able to help

Answer (score 3):

I've it working now. Not perfect but it works.

See the example on stack blitz mentioned in my earlier message.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mensand-rowselect?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Comment: not perfect! this is perfection in a post :D many thanks, although I did tweak your answer slightly to instead use ... @ViewChildren('partRow', {read: ElementRef}) partRows: QueryList<ElementRef>;